# Como usar o PHP na linha de comando?

Tags: php, terminal

É possível utilizar o PHP na linha de comando? Como funciona o uso da linguagem nesse ambiente? É possível desenvolver scripts e executá-los como scripts escritos em shell?

Comment: Eu uso muito, por sinal. Inclusive, na minha máquina, o editor de código está configurado para chamar o executável diretamente, para facilitar o desenvolvimento sem precisar de um servidor de páginas local rodando o tempo todo. "[Como funciona o uso da linguagem nesse ambiente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/361581/revisions)" - dentro do que se pode esperar da linha de comando, funciona normalmente. O que exatamente tem duvida?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Olá tudo bem? Podemos sim utilizar o php com linha de comando.

Exemplo: vamos usar o php em linha de comando para executar um script que exiba a mensagem "Hello terminal";
No caso você cria o arquivo php, por exemplo de nome 'script.php', coloca a mensagem dentro. Após abre o terminal de onde o seu arquivo está e executa qualquer um dos comandos abaixo (o -f no segundo comando vem de 'file', ou seja, o nome do arquivo; mas os dois fazem a mesma coisa, é somente outra forma de executar):

```
php script.php
php -f script.php
```

Exemplo de como ficaria o código:
script.php

```
<?php

echo "Hello terminal!";
```

Saída no prompt de comando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usando o php com linha de comando temos duas variáveis globais importantes:
**[argc](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.argc.php)** e **[argv](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.argv.php)**. O **argc** é o contador de parâmetros passados e enquanto o argv é um array global contendo os parâmetros passados (por padrão o primeiro índice sempre contém o nome do script que está sendo executado).

Podemos passar os parâmetros e usá-los a nosso favor. Vamos fazer um exemplo de passar dois números e imprimir a multiplicação entre eles, mas se forem passados parâmetros a menos do que o necessário iremos imprimir uma mensagem de erro.

Logo, nosso script fica assim:

```
<?php

// O primeiro índice é o nome do arquivo logo temos 3 parâmetros: 0 é o nome do arquivo, 1 é o primeiro número e 2 é o segundo número
if ($argc < 2) {
    echo "Parametros invalidos para executar o script!";
    exit(1);
}
$mult = $argv[1] * $argv[2];

echo "\n O resultado da multiplicacao entre os numeros informados eh: $mult";
echo "\n A quantidade de parametros aceitos e que foram informados sao: $argc";
echo "\n Parametros informados para o script:";
print_r($argv);
```

Nossa saída no terminal fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para saber mais consulte a [documentação sobre Php utilizado em linha de comando](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.commandline.usage.php)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Importante dizer que, obviamente, a pasta (ou diretório) onde está instalado o PHP deve estar na variável de ambiente PATH do sistema operacional utilizado.

Answer (score 6):

É possível, [tem manual sobre isto](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php). Então é só chamar o interpretador da linguagem passando o *script* que pretende executar e eventualmente argumentos para ele.

```
php -f script.php
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Qual a diferença para com e sem `-f` ?

Comment: @isac tem situações que vc tem opções e argumentos, normalmente nesse caso usa `php -opcao1 -f arquivo -opcao2 -opcaoN -- argumento1 argumento2` e só será passado pro PHP o que vier depois do `--`. Já, sem o `-f` até o `--` é tratado como argumento. E, como é PHP, nos dois casos é inconsistente quando você passa alguma coisa antes do `--` que não é uma das opções do PHP  :D (Pelo menos PHP é consistente no que diz respeito a não ser consistente :P )